# Polymorphic associations and Formtastic in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a simple polymorphic association:

```
class Highlight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :highlightable, polymorphic: true
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :highlights, as: :highlightable
end

class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :highlights, as: :highlightable
end
```

In the active_admin form to create a new Highlight how can i assign it to either a Property or a Destination?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a this to the highlight form:

```
f.input : highlightable_type, as: :select, collection: {"Property" => "property", "Destination" => "destination"}
```